# Delete node from firebase database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How to delete a node from FireBase from the [console](https://console.firebase.google.com)? Since it is too big apparently I can't delete it from the console.
Usually I could press on the delete button near the node name, but it says the console it's read only for performance reasons.

Comment: what about calling remove() on the reference?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I would like to do it from the web console of Firebase not from code.

Comment: I don't think you can... wiring up a quick app with @martinjakubik suggestion to do it though would be trivial.

Comment: If your data is too big for the console, use the REST interface to construct a request that deletes the node you want.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Another simple way to delete large nodes is to use the firebase cli

```
firebase use 'your-database'
firebase database:remove '/path/to/node'
```

Comment: I've been working in the browser console for years. This is brilliant!

Answer (score 5):

Navigate to the node which you want to delete. Then import an empty json file (containing just starting and ending curly braces {}) to that particular node. Thats all, the node will no longer exists as it doesn't contain any data. N.B. Works on read only mode as well.

Answer (score 2):

The console becomes read-only when the path you are currently viewing contains too much data:

`Read-only & non-realtime mode activated to improve browser performance
Select a key with fewer records to edit or view in realtime`

You are able to click the plus sign on the left of the node to expand it, but there is not the usual red X to delete that node in this scenario. To see it again, click on one of the sub-nodes, and if that one doesn't contain too much data the red X will appear. You can also use the [Firebase Database REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/) and make curl command line call like this: `curl -X DELETE \
  'https://[PROJECT_ID].firebaseio-demo.com/users/jack/name/last.json'`